# JPA distinct inner join with Condition on joined table

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, jpql

I have two tables below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COLLEGE")
public class College {
private Long collegeId;
private List<Student> students;

@Id
@Column(name = "COLLEGE_ID")
public Long getCollegeId() {
       return this.collegeId;
   }

public void setCollegeId(final Long collegeId) {
       this.collegeId= collegeId;
   }
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "college")
 @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
public List<Student> getStudents() {
        if (this.students== null) {
            this.students= new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return this.students;
    }
public void setStudents(List<Student> students){
     this.students = students
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
public class Student {
   private Long studentId;
   private College college;
   private String name;
   private String department;

@Id
public Long getStudentId() {
    return this.studentId;
  }
public void setStudentId(Long studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
 }

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
@JoinColumn(name = "COLLEGE_ID")
public getCollege() {
    return this.college;
  }
public setCollege(College college) {
    this.college = college;
  }
  ......
  ......
}
```

I want to get the `college` object with list of `students` of a specific `department`. The SQL query is below:

```
select *
from COLLEGE c
inner join STUDENT s on c.COLLEGE_ID= s.collegeId
where c.COLLEGE_ID=12345 and s.DEPARTMENT="ENGINEERING";
```

So far I have tried the below JPA query but it is returning multiple `College` objects.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c
FROM COLLEGE c
INNER JOIN c.students s
where c.collegeId= :collegeid and s.department = :department
```

How to return a single `college` object with list of `students` with filtered `department`?

NOTE: I can't alter the entity objects used here.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Oracle is the DB used here

Comment: You can't. The students of a college are the students of the college. All of them. That's what the javadoc would be if you wrote it: "the students of the college". If you want only some of them, then select them: `select c, s from College c joins c.students s where c.collegeId = :collegeId and s.department = :department`.

Comment: @JBNizet How can I do it in a `JPA` way?

Comment: How is what I suggested "not in a JPA way"? It's a JPQL query.

Comment: @JBNizet I was able to do it using the below Query: `SELECT DISTINCT c
FROM COLLEGE c
JOIN FETCH c.students s
where c.collegeId= :collegeid and s.department = :department`

Comment: @JBNizet will your query return a single `College`  object with list of filtered `Students`? I am asking this because if it works then I need to take the best option.

Comment: No. As I explained, that will not happen. It would break the invariants of the entity: the students collection is supposed to contain all the students of the college, because that's what a OneToMany association is designed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this query, using `JOIN FETCH` instead `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM College c 
       JOIN FETCH c.students s
            WHERE c.collegeId= :collegeid 
                  AND s.department = :department
```

Comment: I already posted the solution myself in the comments, but Thanks for the help. I am accepting your answer as solution.